# Proving the limit in measure of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable and unique (a.e.)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> 1-Let $f_n:X\to\mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of measurable functions, if they converge in measure to a function $f$, then $f$ is measurable and unique (a.e)
>   2- If the sequence is Cauchy in measure, then there is a subsequence $f_{n_i}$converging pointwise a.e. and $f_n$ converges in measure.

This concept of convergence in measure is new to me, I'm just starting with it and I feel I still don't understand quite well how to prove things about this type of convergence.
For 1- it doesn't seem I have to use directly the definition of measurable function (i.e. taking the preimage of an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and checking if it's measurable), so I don't have a clue on how to prove $f$ is measurable. Then for proving $f$is unique a.e this is what I thought:

I need to prove that if there is another function $g$ to which the sequence converges in measure, then the set of points where they differ must be a null set. If I define a sequence of sets as $A_m=\{x:|f(x)-g(x)|<1/m\}$
 and $A=\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$, then $A_m^c$ is an increasing sequence converging to $A^c$, so it would suffy to prove each $A_m^c$ has zero measure.
I've also defined for each $n$ and $m$ the sets $$B_{n,m}=\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|<1/m\} \quad C_{n,m}=\{x:|f_n(x)-g(x)|<1/m\}$$
So, I have the inclusion $A_m^c\subset (B_{n,m}\cap C_{n,m})^c=B_{n,m}^c\cup C_{n,m}^c$ wich holds for all $n$. Now, because of the convergence in measure if I take $\epsilon>0$ there must be some $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n>M$: $$\mu(B_{n,m}^c)<\epsilon/2$$ and $$\mu(C_{n,m}^c)<\epsilon/2$$ This means that I can fit each $A_m^c$ inside of a set of measure as small as I want and i think this is enough to conclude $\mu(A_n)=0$, is it correct?

For 2- I don'tknkw if I can construct the subsequence directly (if so I don'thave any clue on how to proceed) or prove it by contradiction,in that case I don't see how the fact that thre is no subsequence converging pointwise a.e can contradict the sequence being Cauchy in measure.

Any hint or guidance is very welcome. Thanks